# is it possible to execute SCP/RCP/SFTP from linux server to Windows Desktop?

Tags: sftp, scp

I have an Linux server, and I would like to remote copy files from linux server to another Windows OS machine, I have tried this method shown as below and it is not working.

scp -v samplefile username(get it from computer properties in window)@myIP:/c/:

Does anyone know how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method works ONLY if you have a ssh daemon or service running on your windows machine. Since Windows does not have that by default it is a lot easier to use a client to connect to your server (winscp, ssh, telnet from windows to linux).